# Which SDK or API should I use to list and upload files into Office 365 sharepoint document libraries

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepointdocumentlibrary

What is the best way now (and in the near future) to list, upload and download files in a document library in Office 365 Sharepoint? I'm looking for .NET SDK's.

There doesn't seem to be much support documentation available that targets this topic.

There is the OneDrive SDK, the Office 365 Sharepoint SDK and the Graph API, but I can't find good examples. I prefer to make use of SDK's rather than than plain REST calls because I want to make use of the ADAL libraries in .NET for authenticating agains Azure Active Directory.

Any advice or pointing in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**[OneDrive SDK for C#.](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp)**

I've just done SharePoint site item listing and file upload using the [OneDrive SDK for Python](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python), and there is a **[OneDrive SDK for C#](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp)**, which should cover the same functionality.
Just make sure to correctly use the *service discovery*, and select the `SharePoint RootSite` service.

You can read more about my adventures achieving this (including some gotchas) **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39981210/upload-file-to-ms-sharepoint-using-python-onedrive-sdk)**.